# Where can I get a list of job titles/occupations for a dropdown list?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am working on a webpage that will ask about the user's occupation/job title.  I was wondering if there is a good source for something like this that I could use for a dropdown list?  Ideally, I would like a list that is reasonable in length (less than one hundred items) that can cover almost all potential users.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of good data at the US Government website:

http://www.data.gov

Comment: Perhaps a more specific link would have been more helpful? Of, if just providing more general information, perhaps just put this is as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found two sites that have a pretty good list. See [THIS](http://www.collegegrad.com/careers/all.shtml) and [THAT](http://www.careerplanner.com/ListOfCareers.cfm)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but here's an additional answer. The Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) collects a lot of data like this. At this link is a breakdown of occupations (occupation profiles):

http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes_stru.htm

The raw data (XLS) is located at this link and goes back to 1997

http://www.bls.gov/oes/tables.htm

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer ...you can try www.synclist.com I think they have a huge list of job and industry titles that you can download or you can access it using the API